# How to make a stored procedure accessible by a specific user

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SSMS 10.50 to access SQL Server 2008 R2 and **I am very new to SQL coding**. My login id is SA. I created a stored procedure and I want to make it executable by specific users. But I am failing to do so.

When I write these line,

```
create proc GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise
    (@comp varchar(40))
as
begin
    grant execute on GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise to [sgp\deepak.b]
    execute AS USER='sgp\deepak.b'; 

    select * 
    from DD_Customer 
    where Company = @comp;
end 

exec GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise 'Google'
```

I get this error

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Procedure 
GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise, Line 6
The server principal "sgp\deepak.b" is not able to access the 
database "TEMP" under the current security context.
```

Could you please explain what I may have done wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: So, you want this SP to be always executed under `[sgp\deepak.b]` no matter who launch execute?

Comment: @gofr1, Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

First create the procedure

```
create proc GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise
    (@comp varchar(40))
as
begin
    select * 
    from DD_Customer 
    where Company = @comp;
end
go
```

Then grant permissions

```
grant execute on GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise to [sgp\deepak.b];
go
```

Then try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `REVERT;` before the `end` to get back to previous user state. Then remove `grant` statement from SP. Then create SP. Then run this:

```
grant connect on TEMP to [sgp\deepak.b];
grant select on TEMP to [sgp\deepak.b];
grant execute on GetCustomerDetailsCompanyWise to [sgp\deepak.b];
```